# Is there an option to block some content in web browser without ID of that element?

Tags: javascript, block, adblock

Is there an option to block some content in web browser without ID of that element?

I want to hide comments from one user on one website. Because I'm using firefox, I tryed AdBlock extension, but it works only if I know Id... as I understand :)

I know only RELATIVE LINK and NAME, is there any chance to block his comments?  I really like that website, but I have a little problem with this guy and will be better for my heart if it will be hidden for me :)

thanks...

Structure of comments is here

```
<div class="comment odd">
  <div class="clear-block">
    <div class="submitted">
      <span><a href="RELATIVE LINK" title="show profile of user">NAME</a></span>
      &nbsp;    
    </div>
    <table class="comment-wrapper"><tbody><tr><td>
        <div class="content">
        WANT HIDE...
        </div>
    </td></tr></tbody></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could, of course, just not read the person's comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here ya go!

basically it looks for comments with a link with 'bob' (replace with the username) and hides the entire comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/yx58X/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a selector such as this:

```
a[href="RELATIVE LINK"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not your website, you are limited to tricks you can do in your browser.

If you are so inclined you could set up a Greasemonkey script that would filter certain pages from certain websites.  A javascript bookmarklet would also work but in a much more "manual" way.